# How to transfer a file from Google Cloud Storage to Compute Engine instance using gcloud terminal?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I would like to verify my website in Google Search Console by uploading a file to my website - example.com which is hosted on Google Cloud Compute Engine (Wordpress site deployed with Google Cloud Launcher) . It has to be placed on a website as example.com/123googlesearchconsoleexample.html , but I cannot upload it via Cloud Shell from a Google Cloud Storage bucket. 
Is there a way to do this?

I tried gcloud compute copy-files command

```
gcloud compute copy-files gs://example/123googlesearchconsoleexample.html example-prd-vm:~/
```

, but it seems that it does not work in the browser and this is how I would like to do it (without installing SDK).
The error I get is:

> (gcloud.compute.copy-files) All sources must be local files when destination is remote.

Comment: It's not clear to me which terminal you're using, given that you're also talking about wanting to do it from a browser. Are you talking about the Cloud Shell?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about Cloud Shell.

Comment: Okay, that's progress. I suggest you clarify your question to state that, and also what happened when you tried running `gcloud compute copy-files`. (The Cloud Shell should already have the gcloud SDK installed, including both the `gcloud` and `gsutil` commands.)

Comment: You should also clarify what you mean by "my website" - we don't know how your web site is hosted. Presumably it's in GCP somehow, but there are *lots* of ways of hosting websites in GCP.)

Comment: Thanks for comments. I edited the question, so it is more clear in topics you mentioned.

Comment: Right, I think that's answerable now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way of doing it in a single step, but it looks like it should be easy to do in two steps:

```
$ gsutil cp gs://example/123googlesearchconsoleexample.html .
$ gcloud compute copy-files 123googlesearchconsoleexample.html example-prd-vm:~/
```

The first command copies from Google Cloud Storage to the VM running Cloud Shell. The second command then copies from that VM to `example-prd-vm`... it's now copying a local file, so the error you're currently getting won't be applicable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I struggled with this for some time, but in the end I just created a new file in the needed directory.

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet. Our hero.

Comment: Hi Jon, does the file copied to the VM running Cloud Shell only last until you close the Cloud Shell? thanks for your help.

Comment: @ChristianAbella: If you're transferring the file to somewhere in your home directory, it's "mostly persistent" - see https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features in the "persistent disk storage" section for details.

Answer (score 2):

First list all the buckets you have using the following command

```
gsutil ls
```

Use the following command to download a file from your Google Cloud Storage bucket to your local location

```
gsutil cp gs://bucketname/filename local-location
```

You can use the -r option to download a folder from GCS

```
gsutil cp -r gs://bucketname/folder-name local-location
```

You can also use the -m option to download large number of files which performs a parallel (multi-threaded/multi-processing) copy

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://bucketname/folder-name local-location
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to copy one file:

```
gsutil -m cp "gs://yourbucketnam/folder/../filename.txt"
```

In order to copy the whole folder:

```
gsutil -m cp "gs://yourbucketnam/folder"
```

In order to copy a folder and all its contents.